# Using vcpkg to download older libraries

Tags: c++, boost, vcpkg

I'm trying to build a project which requires, among other things, Boost - version 1.51.0.

The project requires Boost to be downloaded using vcpkg. On default, vcpkg downloads the latest version of the package. After a bit of research I saw vcpkg supports versioning. I editted the vcpkg.json file to download Boost version 1.51.0 instead of 1.77.0 (the current latest version on vcpkg).

However, it seems that boost's dependencies (which are also boost libraries, for example boost-accumulators) are still downloaded using version 1.77.0. Is there a way to download these libraries without manually editting the dependencies' json files as well? There are more than 150 of those...

Thanks!

EDIT: I now see the oldest available version of boost on vcpkg is 1.60. If that really is the case, replace 1.51 by 1.60 in my question above.

Answer (score 1):

This is because boost is a meta package.

I believe the easiest solution is to override the dependencies and pin each of them to the version you want.

This process is documented here:

https://vcpkg.io/en/docs/examples/modify-baseline-to-pin-old-boost.html